# supremum of function

Tags: calculus

I've got some homework which I need to give an example to functions that makes this:
$$ \sup f(g(x)) < \sup f(x) $$
I tries some ways but they are all lead that this is what happens: $\sup f(g(x)) = \sup f(x)$

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I voted this down since you did not include all the requirements in your question.

Comment: @RoryDaulton what did I miss?

Comment: I wrote that comment long ago, and the question has been edited since, so I do not remember exactly what I considered to be missing. I cannot vote your question back up but I did add +1 to this comment.

Answer (score 1):

Take $$g: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}:x \mapsto 1 \quad \text{ and } \quad f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}:x \mapsto  e^{-x^2},$$
then for every $x$ we have
$$f(g(x)) = e^{-1} < 1 = f(0)$$
 it follows that 
$$\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f(g(x)) = e^{-1} < 1= e^{-0}=\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote is incorrect in general. For example, for $f(x) = 1$ (a constant function equal to $1$), you know that $\sup f(x) = \sup f(g(x))$ for any function $g$.

What you probably need to prove is that $\sup f(g(x))\leq \sup f(x)$, which can be proven simply by showing that $\sup f(x)$ is the upper bound of $f(g(x))$.

You may wonder why an equality cannot be proven. For that, take a look at the functions $f(x) = -x$ on $[-1,1]$ and $g(x) = x^2$. Now, it is obvious that the suppremum (and maximum) of $f$ is equal to $1$, however, $f(g(x)) = -(x^2) < 0<1$, so in this case, $\sup(f(g(x)) < \sup f(x).$

Comment: and what is $supf(x)$ ? It need to be constant.

Comment: @user3708158 In my example, it is perfectly simple to calculate what $\sup f$ is. Take a pen, a sheet of paper and draw a graph of $f$. It's not hard.

Comment: Sorry. forgot to mention that f has to has inf and sup aswell to all rational numbers.

Comment: @user3708158 And how does that change my point? Have you even **read** my answer? Read it and try to think about it. If you read my answer and understand it (which you will if you read it and think at least $30$ seconds about it), you will understand what to do.

Comment: sup $f(x) = -x $ is infinity. isn't it?

Comment: @user3708158 True, the supremum of $-x$ is infinity. But, as I said, my $f$ is defined on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: yes, but the f is defined to all rational numbers, and not to just $[-1,1]$. $f$ also need to have $sup$ and $inf$ which are not $+-$ infinity. sorry for misunderstanding. that is the problem.

Comment: @user3708158 OK, I understand. But do you understand why in my example, the supremum of $f\circ g$ is smaller than the supremum of $f$? If you *truly* understand why this is so, an example for $f$ defined on all rational numbers should be trivial to find.

Comment: I truly understand. but I have no example in my head. that's why I published and asked it. do you have any Idea? Thank you and sorry.

Comment: @user3708158 I am saying this with the utmost respect and want to help you with this sentence. Do not think I am trying to insult you, but: *it is obvious you either do not truly understand or you have put no effort into truly understanding it*.

Comment: It's ok, I am not insulted. probably I don't understand this concept well enought. I am sitting on this for 3 hours with no stops(except for asking and looking on wolframalph for functions). Anyway, If you have any example to give me I'll more then appreciate it.

Comment: @user3708158 Here is a hint to think about: why, in my example, is the supremum of $f(g(x))$ smaller than the supremum of $f$? What is it about $f(g(x))$ that it cannot reach the supremum of $f$?